# Is there a way in SQL Server Management Studio to number/identify query results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, display

When using SQL Server 2014 and SMSS 2014, is there some way to identify which query is which results when the SQL output is set to `Results to Grid`?

```
 DECLARE @foo TABLE (ID int, data int)
 DECLARE @bar TABLE (ID int, data varchar(1))

 INSERT INTO @foo VALUES (1,10),(2,11),(3,11),(4,11)
 INSERT INTO @bar VALUES (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d')

 --Query 1
 SELECT * FROM @foo

 --Query 2
 SELECT * FROM @bar
```

Sometimes I string a several queries together so I can see the steps of my algorithm and I cannot always identify which results are from which query.

[image: QueryResultsGrid]

Comment: What about `Select '1' query_Num, * from ...`?

Comment: you have 1 grid result per "SELECT" and they are in order. there is no other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT 'query 1', * FROM @foo

 SELECT 'query 2', * FROM @bar
```

Use this only for test queries. Of course I usually put something more useful about the query than just "query 1", like "budgets before adjustment" then "budgets after adjustment" for query 2.

I also tend to wrap these types of test queries in a test process where I have a a debug value as a parameter and then write the query:

```
IF @Debug = 1
BEGIN
  SELECT 'query 1', * FROM @foo
END
```